# Form trouble: radio button ->yes,no or null

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm sure I am missing something quite simple, but I have a form with a few yes/no inputs - type=radio. I have made the default NULL. YES is significant, NO is significant and NULL means user has never answered the question. When I UPDATE the db with user's selections, my NULL values are overwritten with 0 even though NO is not selected. I've read that if user doesn't choose either YES or NO that variable is NOT SET, therefore,

```
$licensedYN = (isset($_POST['licensed'])&&!empty($_POST['licensed']))?$_POST['licensed']:NULL;
    $malpracticeYN = (isset($_POST['malpractice']))?$_POST['malpractice']:NULL;

$sqlAdd = $db->query("INSERT INTO temp (licensedYN,malpracticeYN) VALUES ('$licensedYN','$malpracticeYN')");
```

How do I get NULL to be inserted into DB and not '0'?

Comment: What is the column defined as?

Comment: My column is defined as tinyint(1) /null=yes/default=NULL

Answer (score 0):

To allow NULL as a value in your `licensedYN` column... Run this query..

```
ALTER TABLE temp MODIFY licensedYN varchar(255) null;
```

This would allow you store null values in your db.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just remove the quotes from the query and place it in the value as follows:

```
$licensedYN = (isset($_POST['licensed']) && !empty($_POST['licensed']))? "'{$_POST['licensed']}'" : 'NULL';
$malpracticeYN = (isset($_POST['malpractice'])) ? "'{$_POST['malpractice']}'": 'NULL';

$sqlAdd = $db->query("INSERT INTO temp (licensedYN,malpracticeYN) VALUES ($licensedYN,$malpracticeYN)");
```

In any case, you should consider working with prepared statements instead of concatenating strings. You will prevent many problems as sql injections, boost the query execution time and will not have headaches with quotation anymore...